# Слайдер bootstrap не отображается

Tags: html5, bootstrap, frontend, slider

При создании слайдера ничего не отображается, при просмотре элемента в браузере показывает пустое поле

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style(1).css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 header" size="20" >
            <button type="button" class="menu_butn" >Menu</button>
            <p class="text one_show" > Site</p>
            <img src="practice_logo.svg" alt="Logo company" align="right" top="0" class="one_show">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 navrow">
            <div class="nav">Home</div>
            <div class="nav">Products</div>
            <div class="nav">About</div>
            <div class="nav">Find us</div>
        </div>
    </div>   

    <div class="row row_2">
        <div class="col-md-6 sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><div>Home</div></li>
                <li><div>Products</div></li>
                <li><div>About</div></li>
                <li><div>Find us</div></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li class="active" data-target="carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0">

                </li>
                    <li class="active" data-target="carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1">

                </li>
                    <li class="active" data-target="carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2">

                    </li>     
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="1st_slide.jpg" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item ">
                        <img src="2nd_slide.jpg" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item ">
                        <img src="3rd_slide.png" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Из приведенного Вами кода не видно - у Вас подключены `js`?:

Да и оптимально взять полностью код слайдера с официального источника https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/#slides-only

Там разные варианты, на любой вкус и все рабочие.

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
      </head>
      <body>
    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: First slide"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#555" dy=".3em">First slide</text></svg>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Second slide"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#666"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#444" dy=".3em">Second slide</text></svg>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Third slide"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#555"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#333" dy=".3em">Third slide</text></svg>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
    
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня и скопированый bootstrap не работает. Такая же проблема. И js подключены. Забыл просто вставить

Comment: Он не может не работать, если Вы вставили все js и css с первоисточника ПРАВИЛЬНО - проверьте внимательно это и нет ли сторонних включений какого либо js, который нарушает работу.